# Extracting data from a manifest and use the data to get updates

Tags: c#, md5, updates

I am creating a launcher for a game a friend and I are creating.

I am trying to read the update manifest to get what new files I need to download

Right now I have the file lay'ed out but I don't know how to read it

Lines of the files are like this Md5 then File
Like checksum.md5 would contain
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e *apples.txt

I am stumped I have try'ed putting it into 2 separate lists with

```
thearray.replace(" ", "").split('*');
```

But it is very lengthily and does not seem like i need such long code for this.
I need from the line of the file is the file to read from the current directory (i can do this if i can some how split/organize it)

Right now heres what i tryed to go off of but stumped..

```
var main = new frmMain();
if (File.Exists("checksums.md5")) { File.Delete("checksums.md5"); }
main.Download(updateurl + "checksums.md5", "checksums.md5");
string[] checksumfile = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("checksums.md5").Replace(" ", "").Split('*');
```

What should I do now to get this to work the way I want?.. Checking all files with the checksum.md5 and put the files that need updated into a list to be updated later..

To be clear (I don't explain things well) files in the checksum.md5 will have path's like so
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e *folder\apples.txt
On the website the file would be in updateurl/files/folder/apples.txt
On the client/launcher the file would be in .\folder\apples.txt

Thank you for reading! I know how to do the basic things like, To be used and stuff just the idea has stumped me..

```
public static string updateurl = "http://localhost/files/";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

It's a very useful tool for manipulating text.

If your files look like this:

> [checksum][space]*[filepath][end of line]
>
> [checksum][space]*[filepath][end of line]
>
> [checksum][space]*[filepath][end of line]
>   . . .

this pattern should work:

```
    string pattern = @"(?<= [*])[^\r\n]*";

    var matches = Regex.Matches(@sourceString, @pattern);
    foreach (Match m in matches) 
    {
        Console.Writeline(m.Value);
    }
```

Regex class also has a Replace method that is far more flexible than String.Replace

**EDIT**

I don't know if it helps or if I completely misunderstood you again :) Some idea how to organize your data:

```
List<FileData> result = (from a in Regex.Split(s, @"\r\n").Cast<string>().Select(a => Regex.Split(a, @" [*]"))
                         select new FileData 
                         {
                             Checksum= a[0],
                             Filepath = a[1],
                             ShouldUpdate = FileData.CheckShouldUpdate(a[0],a[1])
                         }).ToList();
```

or:

```
List<FileData> result = (from a in Regex.Split(s, @"\r\n").Cast<string>().Select(a => Regex.Split(a, @" [*]"))
                         where FileData.CheckShouldUpdate(a[0], a[1])
                         select new FileData 
                         {
                             Checksum = a[0],
                             Filepath = a[1]
                         }).ToList();
```

...

```
class FileData
        {
            public string Checksum { get; set; }
            public string Filepath { get; set; }
            public bool ShouldUpdate { get; set; }
            public FileData() { }
            public static bool CheckShouldUpdate(string checksum, string filename)
            {
                // some check logic here...
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thank you! You have helped me and I am eternally grateful!

Comment: Im getting one error since i set it up, Index was outside the bounds of the array. This is on | List<FileData> result